# How to both display a command line's output on console and save the output into a text file?

Tags: command-line, apt

How can I run `sudo apt-get install` by **BOTH** seeing the process of installation (long in my case) **and** saving its output into a text file ?

Comment: Is only about `apt-get` right?

Comment: @Braiam I think the solution I accepted can be applied to all other commands, do you think so ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the `script` command. It will copy everything that goes to screen in a file

```
script -c "sudo apt-get install things" script-file.script
```

Comment: `script` sends the command output to a file, but does not show it on the screen.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23. Did you try the command ? script **does** send output to screen.

Comment: Furthermore, `tee` won't redirect `stderr` to the file, whereas `script` will. The formating of `tee` is nicer though (on my laptop, `script` added lots of un-necessary newlines)

Comment: I did.  I ran `script -c "history" ~/hist.txt` and saw output indicating `Script started` and `Script done`, but I didn't see output from the actual command on the screen.

Comment: I tested this solution before I accepted it: it really shows the output to the screen and saves it also to a text file. It is a simple a command and nothing additional to install.

Comment: Well that is weird. I tested `script` with `apt-get install somepackage` and it worked fine, but with `history`, both my shell and my output file were blank

Comment: That *is* weird.  I also just tested it with `apt-get update` and it worked just fine...but not with `history`?  Wow.  @Exore, good answer...+1 from me.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 `history` is a shell builtint, not an external command. What happens is : 1) script starts, 2) script searches the history command, does not find it, so it guesses it should run this via a shell. 3) script runs the command `history` **via a shell** 4) a new shell starts and executes the history internal command. Since this is a new non interactive shell, history has nothing to say.

Comment: `script` can also be run interactively.  Just type `script` at the command prompt.  You will get a new shell, and any commands you type will have their output saved.  Type `exit` to end the shell and save the file.  By default, the output is called `typescript` and it will contain everything shown on your screen, whether you typed it, or it was the output of a command. The `history` command should still be available in the new shell as well.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the `tee` command to accomplish this.

```
sudo apt-get install someapp 2>&1 | tee ~/someappInstall.txt
```

[Look here for more info](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utee.htm), or execute `man tee`

Note: As others have mentioned, `2>&1` is necessary to redirect STDERR to STDOUT to catch any errors.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21) for a good explanation of what `2>&1` actually does.

Comment: I'd add "2>&1" before the "|"

Comment: Good call.  Edit made.

Comment: This is more practical than `script` since the command doesn't have to be quoted. So advantages like bash completion is easier to accomplish.

Comment: @Dan: script doesn't need the `-c "something ..."`: if will then drop you to a shell, and finished when you exit that shell. Allows multiple commands, etc. Plus it keeps more "formatting" infos, allowing replaying of some more things (like : clear screen, etc) (but that also can mess up the output... ymmv)

Comment: @Dan + works with functions, aliases, builtins and even command groups and subshells. This should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: you could use `|&` instead of `2>&1 |` in bash

Answer (score 15):

`tee` will do the job as required.

To capture the output into a file, use:

```
sudo apt-get install your_software | tee log_file.txt
```

This will only capture the output, but not any error messages.  If you would also like to record error messages, modify the command to be:

```
sudo apt-get install your_software 2>&1  | tee log_file.txt
```

Comment: Or, since `bash` [supports the `|&` operator](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), `sudo apt-get install your_software |& tee log_file.txt` will pipe both [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) and [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) to `tee`. (Kudos to [J.F. Sebastian](http://askubuntu.com/users/3712/j-f-sebastian) who [suggested this elsewhere](http://askubuntu.com/q/485495#comment651736_485499).)

Answer (score 9):

One of the beauty of apt-get (and APT in general) is that they store log files for almost everything, even the terminal output of any command that you run trough, in the `/var/log/apt`. For example, this is the last entry in my `/var/log/apt/term.log`:

```
Log started: 2014-06-20  16:46:08
(Reading database ... 252472 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xdotool (1:3.20130111.1-3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Log ended: 2014-06-20  16:46:33
```

Now, comparing with the actual output:

```
➜  ~  sudo apt-get remove xdotool 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libxdo3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xdotool
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 135 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 252472 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xdotool (1:3.20130111.1-3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
```

It saved me several lines that are not relevant in most cases, and it does automatically. So, you don't need any extra command to do what you want to do, apt-get does it for you.

Answer (score 1):

try [tee](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/tee.1.html) command.
You can found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670784/redirecting-bash-stdout-stderr-to-two-places) some examples.

Simple usage:

```
  <command> | tee file
```

example:

```
  sudo apt-get install whatYouWant | tee outputFile
```