# How to get the Input and output in a terminal to a text file?

Tags: command-line, input, output

I want to create a text file which will add each command I am going to run on the terminal as a new line entry in the text file. i.e., I need to keep a record of what are the things I'm doing in the terminal. Further if I can keep a record of outputs I'm getting in the terminal, along with the inputs in the terminal, as a text file, it will be much better.

Each time I forget a command I have to search again in the Internet for the command. 
Can I can make a file like above?

Comment: Yeah, you can run the command `history` to see a list of run commands. Run all commands with the `>> file.txt` and it will all be saved there.

Comment: `history` is nice.

Comment: ...but there are several more, for example this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/485495/how-to-both-display-a-command-lines-output-on-console-and-save-the-output-into

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/script.1.html) to make typescript of terminal session. It will record all the inputs and output to a file. To start recording type in terminal,

```
$ script
```

Go on doing your regular job. To end the recording use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. All the typescript will be saved in the file `typescript` located at the directory where you opened the terminal.

To save all the log in your desired file, use

```
$ script /path/to/mylogfile.txt
```

Usually `script` comes with default Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

Comment by [tim](https://askubuntu.com/users/186134/tim) will solve the first part of the question.

Running `history` on terminal shows the commands previously ran on terminal.

Running `history >> file.txt` on terminal creates file.txt in home directory which has as entry the commands previously ran on terminal.