# mplayer script output redirect?

Tags: command-line

I am working on mplayer script and I am trying to get this command to ( at the same time) display on terminal and write to file. 
Whatever input.anyone has would be greatly appreciated.
This is a command.

```
Mplayer -ddd-device /dev\#device dvd\\#dvdtitlenum -vf propdetect alang.eng -sid 20 and_ grep oe ']0-9[*':'[0-9,]*':'[0-9]*':,'[0-9]*'
```

Comment: Linux is case sensitive so you will need to fix that as `Mplayer` should be `mplayer`

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the video output to write to a file or the terminal output to write to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has several answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485495/how-to-both-display-a-command-lines-output-on-console-and-save-the-output-into). However, reading the answers, it seems like there is a details missing, namely what your script (or `mplayer`) will detect as output.

- If you do `script -c myscript out.log`, the programs run by `myscript`  will detect that their output is a *terminal*, so they might try to produce fancier output, involving hidden control sequences, like colors and cursor movements. The file `out.log` will contain those sequences, too.
- If you do `myscript 2>&1 | tee out.log`, the programs in `myscript` will detect that their output is a *file*, so they might disable fancier formatting.